# PHP's db2_bind_param()

Tags: php, data-binding, db2

Why do you have to specify variable names as a string value with this function? Why can't I just use the variable name directly? This seems very silly to me.

Example:
    db2_bind_param($prepared, 1, "foo1");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.db2-bind-param.php), it is the variable, to which the resource is bound to:

```
bool db2_bind_param(resource $stmt , int $parameter-number , string $variable-name, ...)
```

That way, you have a clean signature, because it always returns a boolean and no other data type. Other functions return either false or a resource. I believe, that the library has been ported from a strongly typed language like c or c++. In these languages, you can only specify one return type in the signature - something like `bool|resource db2_bind_param(...)` does not work.

In the end you are right: In a loosely typed language like PHP, you do not need it.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with what a clean signatures, but your explanation makes sense. So in C/C++ if a function is declared as int or bool they are only allowed to return int or bool?

Comment: a function signature is what you call the tupel of return type, function name and argument types.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it's doing something like:

```
function db2_bind_param($stmt, $position, $name) {
   global $$name;
   $$name = &$stmt[$position];
}
```

just a guess, though...

Answer (score 1):

That way you can bind a set of variables programmatically, as

```
$db_vars = array("foo1","foo2");

for($i=1; $i<=sizeof($db_vars); ++$i)
  db2_bind_param($prepared, $i, $db_vars[$i]);
```

You can then get the values programmatically using variable variables:

```
foreach($db_vars as $var)
  echo $var,'=',$$var,"\n";
```

If the `$variable-name` argument were expected to be the variable itself, a basic feature of the function abstraction would break, since you could pass in exactly the same *value* and get different results:

```
$foo = 'hello';
db2_bind_param2($prepared, 1, $foo); // feasible, but...

db2_bind_param2($prepared, 1, 'hello'); // should give the same result as above, but what would it be?
```

Comment: I honestly can't see why both ways wouldn't work with your last example :(